# Regex spaces between chars except the beginning Java

Tags: java, regex, filter

I've been struggling my mind for the past couple of hours in order to get the following behaviour in a sentence of characters:

`John is $@^&%$#@&$^12(random chars...)` - match
`John is $@^&%$#@&$^12(random chars...)`    - match (some spaces at the end)
    `John is $@^&%$#@&$^12(random chars...)` - unmatch (some spaces at the beginning)

I could not find any answer to get the right regex to be used in Java for a filter in edit text.
Must specify that I am not allowed to change project setting therefore some errors pop-up such as:

```
'\s' and '\' escape sequences are not supported at language level '8'
Illegal escape character in string literal
```

Here are a few variants that I tried:

```
"^[^ ]+.+"
"^[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+-={};',.<>?/:][ ]*.*"
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$"
"^[^ ]+( .+)*$"
"^\\w+( \\w+)*$"
"^- (\\w+( \\w+)*)$"
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]$"
"^[^ ]+[\\s]*"
"^[^-\\s][\w\s-]+$"
```

None of them works

**EDIT**

Here is all the code:

```
        final EditText nameInput = line2.findViewById(R.id.input_value);
        nameInput.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new NoSpaceStartInputFilter()});

private static class NoSpaceStartInputFilter implements InputFilter {
        
        private Pattern mPattern;
        
        public NoSpaceStartInputFilter() {
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[^ ]+.+");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+-={};',.<>?/:][ ]*.*");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[^ ]+( .+)*$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+( \\w+)*$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^- (\\w+( \\w+)*)$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[^ ]+[\\s]*");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[^-\\s][\w\s-]+$");
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!\\s+\\S)\\S*\\s.*");
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
            Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(charSequence);
            if (!matcher.matches())
                return "";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the Java code you are using to match? If all your requirement is not to match any spaces in the beginning then `^\\S` should probably just do the trick, but it depends on the regex method you chose.

Comment: So what you are asking is to match all strings that don't start with whitespace(s)? I mean you _can_ use regex here, but why not simply look at the first character, if it is a whitespace or not to determine if the string is valid?

Comment: Maybe `text.matches("^(?!\\s+\\S)\\S*\\s.*")`? I.e. there must be a whitespace but not at the start? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0EepmG/1).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I edited the question and put the whole code. Using your answer then it seems that the edit text removes every char introduced after introducing a new one

Comment: @maloomeister I want to let a use introduce in the edit text any chars except starting with whitespace

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your answer but it requires to add a whitespace in order to show the chars in the edit text... So, if no space included then it won't display the introduced characters

Comment: So, remove that requirement: `text.matches("^(?!\\s).*")` or `text.matches("\\S.*")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew GREAT! Your a saviour! The first one still lets me introduce space at the beginning. However ```"\\S.*"``` is the answer! Would be nice to add the answer in the feed to mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: You shouldn't have used `matches` to begin with, but `find()`. The method `matches()` behaves as if the pattern has anchors `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
text.matches("\\S.*")
```

The `String#matches` requires a full string match and the pattern matches a string that matches

- `\S` - a non-whitespace as the first char and then
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

To allow line break chars, use

```java
text.matches("(?s)\\S.*")
text.matches("\\S[\\w\\W]*")
```